# how to load a list of custom UserAccount from AppSettings?

Tags: c#, .net-core

My Identity Settings class:

```
public abstract class UserAccount
    {
        [Required]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdministratorUserAccount : UserAccount
    {
        public string Company{ get; set; }
    }

    public class ManagerUserAccount : UserAccount
    {
        public string AdministratorEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public class IdentitySettings
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1)]
        public List<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    }
```

in startup.cs:

```
    services.Configure<T>(configuration.GetSection("Identity"));
```

in DBInitializer, the list of UserAccounts is always empty.

```
            var defaultUserAccountsSettings = services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentitySettings>>().Value;
```

How to be able to get the data from appsettings.json serialized in a list of UserAccount where UserAccount can be Administrator or Manager.

Comment: Why don't you just put two lists of account in your app setting? `AdministratorsList` and `ManagersList`. Then you can easily map them to C# classes.

Comment: For the example I set 2 types, but in my code there is more. Your solution works, but I'm looking for something more adaptive. If I don't find another solution, I will probably use yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the option binding doesn't know which concreate class object to create to fill up the list since `UserAccount` is abstract.

To make the scenario work, we need to have a way to control the creation of the object somehow.

How about putting the list in an additional json (test-data.json for example), read it by a jsonSerializer, and fill up the list:

```cs
services.AddOptions<IdentitySettings>().Configure(idSettings => {
    idSettings.UserAccounts = JsonConvert.DeserialzeObject<IdentitySettings>(...); // Whatever deserializer that works.
});
```

Here's how to creating object with TypeNameHandling with Newtonsoft.Json: [Deserialize a List<AbstractClass> with newtonsoft.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038441/deserialize-a-listabstractclass-with-newtonsoft-json).

=====

After I read the comment, I realized you relies on Options pattern with various providers. In that case, technically, one approach could be parsing of IConfigurationSection like this:

```
var x = Configuration.GetSection("UserAccounts").AsEnumerable();
```

The result of the KeyValue pair will be a bit tedious to deal with, like:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| UserAccount | null |
| UserAccount:0 | null |
| UserAccount:0:FirstName | Mike |
| UserAccount:0:LastName |  |
| ... | ... |
| UserAccount:1 | null |
| UserAccount:1:FirstName | ... |
| ... |  |

Group it by the index will results to `Group<int, IEnumerable<KeyVaultPair<string, string>>`.

Create a factory method like `static bool TryBuildAccount(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> input, out UserAccount account);` to create one object by 1 group.

Then, the question is, it it really worth it? Will it become too complex when there's change to the Account class.

I would probably take Hassan Monjezi's suggestion unless there's better way that doesn't require that much tedious code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It avoids the difficulty of binding data from appsettings, for sure your solution will work but I need to have it in AppSettings to be able to update the list easily from Azure Configuration.